# Create a circuit with max 6 NAND gates

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, nand

We need to make a logic circuit, the given function is:

*f= (AB) + (not(C)) + (not(A)D)*

I already tried a bit, and I can manage to make a circuit with 7 NAND gates but not with less...
Could anyone help me with that, please?
I also added a 3 NAND input gate, which is not allowed...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5NBkt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Then at least show what you have and how you got there. Use the schematic entry tool to draw the schematic of your solution.

Comment: Did you apply all the Rules of Logic? ( e.g. distributive)

Comment: Have you studied combinational logic design. covering logic minimisation, De Morgan's rules, and Karnaugh mapping? Have you tried any of them here?

Comment: Brian, I tried , but I just can't figure it out ...

Comment: Does it help if the last NAND gate must be f=not(C AND f(ABD)) ,  leaving some function of ABD

Comment: Your example circuit can't work. That final 3-in NAND is the same as an OR gate with inverted inputs, so I don't think you are ORing in not-C there (in fact, the whole thing looks wrong to me on its face.)

Comment: "I tried" doesn't help. Show your try - for example, your Kmap and minimised form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take it that this is early in a class and that you've not yet been taught enough logic manipulation to be able to rigorously develop a desired result here.

Let me start with something quite simple. A NAND is the exact same thing as an OR, with inverted inputs. You can work this out for yourself once you know [De Morgan's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) two laws:

1. the negation of a disjunction is the conjunction of the negations.
2. the negation of a conjunction is the disjunction of the negations.

So: \$F_0=\overline{X\cdot Y}=\overline{X}+\overline{Y}\$. Handy to know.

From the above, now:

$$\begin{align*}
\overline{X\cdot Y}&=\overline{C} + \left(A\cdot B + \overline{A}\cdot D\right)\\\\
&=\overline{\overline{\overline{C} + \left(A\cdot B + \overline{A}\cdot D\right)}}\\\\
&=\overline{C\cdot\overline{A\cdot B + \overline{A}\cdot D}}\\\\
& & \therefore X &= C\\\\
& & Y&=\overline{A\cdot B + \overline{A}\cdot D}
\end{align*}$$

So that is one NAND, as follows:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwJANq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The problem has been reduced. Continue, by focusing on the remaining unresolved portion:

$$\begin{align*}
\overline{X\cdot Y}&=\overline{A\cdot B + \overline{A}\cdot D}\\\\
&=\overline{\overline{\overline{A\cdot B + \overline{A}\cdot D}}}\\\\
&=\overline{\overline{\overline{A\cdot B}\:\cdot\:\overline{\overline{A}\cdot D}}}\\\\
& & \therefore X &= \overline{A\cdot B}\\\\
& & Y&=\overline{\overline{A}\cdot D}
\end{align*}$$

Clearly, the double-negation we are left with means we need to invert the output of the NAND (to make an AND.) So now:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRWcOr.png)</sup>

Then quickly:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6JQd1.png)</sup>

Now, the remainder is also obvious:

$$\begin{align*}
\overline{X\cdot Y}&=\overline{\overline{A}\cdot D}\\\\
& & \therefore X &= \overline{A}\\\\
& & Y&=D
\end{align*}$$

So:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flu3rX.png)</sup>

Now, this process works. And it can work for fairly complex expressions, too. But it won't necessarily find optimal solutions. There are methods to help with that process.

Comment: Thanks! Definitely a good documentation for the community!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the circuit made using [Quine–McCluskey algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine%E2%80%93McCluskey_algorithm) which is functionally identical to [Karnaugh map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map). Function mapped using the tool below.

[image]

P.S. You may find this useful https://sontrak.com/

Comment: Looks like that is straight out of Logic Friday's logic diagram display generator, too.

Comment: Yes it's made with that tool which implements it